# Finite chain condition - Variation of Martin's Axiom statement

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, order-theory, cardinals, forcing

In the following $k$ and $w$ will be cardinal numbers.

Consider [the classical statement $MA(k)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom):

> For any partial order $P$ satisfying the countable chain condition (hereafter $ccc$) and any family $D$ of dense sets in $P$ such that $|D| = k$, there is a filter $F$ on $P$ such that $F \cap d$ is non-empty for every $d$ in $D$

Let's generalize it to the statement $MA(w, k)$ that replaces the $ccc$ by any width $w$, stating:

> For any partial order $P$ satisfying that every strong antichain is of cardinality $less$ than $w$ [...etc]

Eg. $MA(\aleph_1, k) = MA(k)$

Of course, $MA(w, k)$ implies $MA(w', k')$ for every $w' \geq w$ and $k' \geq k$

Now, I was wondering why $MA$ was so specific about antichains being countable, so to motivate the classical definition I tried mapping $MA$'s validity for each $w$ and $k$ pair. So far I've got:

- $MA(w, k)$ is true for all $k \leq \aleph_0$
- $MA(\aleph_1, 2^{\aleph_0}) = MA(2^{\aleph_0})$ is false, and then so it is for any $w$ and $k$ equal or greater
- $MA(\aleph_1, k) = MA(k)$ is independent from but consistent with $ZFC$ for every $\aleph_1 \leq k < 2^{\aleph_0}$
- $MA(\aleph_2, \aleph_1)$ is false, and then so it is for any $w$ and $k$ equal or greater

So $MA$ is no use stated for longer than countable antichains. But the case I can't figure out is for $w = \aleph_0$ and $k > \aleph_0$.

So the question is: Why $ccc$? What can be said about the validity of $MA$ when stated for posets sastisfying that every strong antichain is finite but given an uncountable number of dense sets? Does a filter always or never exist? Is it equivalent to the case $w = \aleph_1$ (ie. is allowing arbitrarily long but finite antichains equivalent to allowing countable ones too)?

Comment: You're missing/ignoring the requirement that the forcing notions must be separative.

Comment: I'm confused about your notation. Perhaps use $\rm\LaTeX$ in a more coherent way?

Comment: @NotMike I'm very new to this, and I don't understand why is that required in any sense for any of my statements/questions

Comment: Replacing "ccc" by uncountable cardinals is a *very* difficult problem. Recently James Cummings, Mirna Dzamonja, and Itay Neeman have proposed a nice generalization. You can find it on arXiv. Other than this, you'd venture well into generalized properness, which is depressingly convoluted and hard to understand, main works are by Shelah and Roslanowski.

Comment: Finite chain condition implies that the forcing is trivial, by the way. If all chains are finite, then they are bounded. Then by taking the separative quotient (which preserves maximality strong antichains) you can prove that every condition lies above an atom.

Comment: @NotMike You don't need separativity as a hypothesis, it's just that non-separative posets aren't interesting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, but wouldn't know how to clarify

Comment: My point about $\rm\LaTeX$ is that you seem to know what it is, using it for $\aleph$ notation. But you insist on using **w** instead of $\omega$, for example. Or < instead of $<$. Why not use *just* $\rm\LaTeX$ for your math parts and not this odd mishmash of boldface and math?

Comment: @AsafKaragila "w" is for "width," they're allowing it to be an arbitrary cardinal.

Comment: @Noah: Ah, that makes more sense, but still the typesetting is awful and makes it hard to read (exactly because many less-familiar users would use w to mean $\omega$ and k to mean $\kappa$, hence my misunderstanding).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'll try to Latex it up a bit after reading the replies, but 'w' is intended to be any cardinal, not omega

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm a very less-familiar user, so tell me if that $k$ is a special value like omega or just a typography convention for readability (btw, I'm on a terrible keyboard and simply counld't find my way through it)

Comment: No, $k$ is fine. But *exactly* because your post is "not $\rm\LaTeX$-savvy", it is easy to confuse the choices you made for notation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Heh. Making it a requirement.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I get it, it really matters for readability.

Comment: @NotMike I'm not sure what you mean - the statement is true regardless of whether it's included or not, so why is it a requirement?

Comment: @AsafKaragila When you said "Replacing "ccc" by uncountable cardinals", do you mean that my last statement was false?

Comment: I mean that there are a lot inherent difficulties in forcing axioms which do not revolve around $\omega$ in some significant way.

Comment: @NoahSchweber it was an attempt at levity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.05426) the paper you refer to?

Comment: @Noah: Indeed that is the paper I am referring to.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Although I appreciate the insight on the subject, in this particular case isn't it trivial replacing $ccc$? Correct me if I'm overseeing something, but of the four items I posted the first and fourth ones would render $MA(w, k)$ trivial when uncountable antichains are allowed (that is for all $w \geq \aleph_2$ in my definition, as $w = \aleph_1$ would be $ccc$)

Comment: @AsafKaragila To clarify on the fourth item ($MA(\aleph_2, \aleph_1)$ is false): Consider $P = Fn(\aleph_0, \aleph_1)$ and the dense sets $H_\alpha = \{\,p \in P \mid \alpha \text{ is in the image of p } \}$ and $D_n = \{\,p \in P \mid \text{ n is in the domain of p} \}$. These are $\aleph_1$ dense sets on $P$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$, but an intersecting filter would be a surjective function

Comment: The point is not to "just change ccc", but also to get something which is consistent and helpful in proving similar consequences to what MA provides us with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that a poset where all strong antichains have finite width is **trivial** - at least, as far as forcing is concerned - and so the corresponding variant of Martin's Axiom is trivial too.

---

To see that such forcings are trivial, the key point is the following:

> Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a poset with an element $p$ such that every $q_1,q_2\le p$ have a common extension $r$ (that is, $p$ doesn't bound any nontrivial strong antichain). Then there is a $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter *in the ground model already*.

The proof is simple: let $G$ be the set of all conditions compatible with $p$.

Now suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is a poset where every strong antichain is finite. I claim that $\mathbb{P}$ has such a "trivializing" element $p$. For if not, we can inductively define a  map $t$ from $2^{<\omega}$ to $\mathbb{P}$ such that:

- $\sigma\prec\tau\implies t(\sigma)\ge t(\tau)$.
- $t(\sigma0)\perp t(\sigma1)$.

But then the set $$\{t(0), t(10), t(110), t(1110), ...\}$$ forms an infinite strong antichain in $\mathbb{P}$.

In fact, we can do even better (since having only finite strong antichains is preserved by passing from $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathbb{P}_{\le s}$):

> If $\mathbb{P}$ has only finite strong antichains, then the set of "trivializing" $p$ is dense in $\mathbb{P}$; so *every* $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter is already in the ground model. *(And consequently, we have "${\bf MA(\aleph_0,\infty)}$.")*

So such a poset really is trivial (in the sense of forcing), not just "possibly trivial," as is the corresponding variant of Martin's Axiom.

Comment: Thanks. It was my intuition that the problem would trivilize like that, but I hadn't yet matured the subject enough to prove it.